# Multiple items with the same ID in the view - ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am building a web application using ZF2 and Doctrine.  I have a view containing a base form to which the user can add multiple instances of a fieldset, the filedsets are added via HTML template and js cloning.  We are making use of the Doctrine hydrator and cascade=persist to write to the dB.  It is all working but I am concerned when the fieldsets are added it results in multiple items with the same ID which breaks w3 standards.  Has anyone a solution or work around for this?  Or would it be considered acceptable in this instance?

An example of one fieldset element:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'glassAssemblyID',
        'attributes' => array(               
            'type'=> 'hidden',
            'id' => 'glassAssemblyID',
        ),
    ));
```

Many thanks
James

Comment: uuid() is your friend

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy one.  Just just change your code to:

```
$this->add(array(
    //'name' => 'glassAssemblyID',
    'attributes' => array(               
        'type'=> 'hidden',
      //'id' => 'glassAssemblyID',
    ),
));
```

No point in putting out an element id which is obviously not being used.

If you really feel you do need ids for some reason then put out something like EntityType-id for your ids.

Comment: I _think_ (can't test it right now) this won't work since ZF2 automatically attaches an ID to every input if the user hasn't defined one.

Comment: Sure but it will be the element name and will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ID in JavaScript after cloning the element.

Comment: Problem is that he is using the ZF2 server side framework, not javascript.

Comment: See what OP wrote: "the filedsets are added via HTML template and js cloning"